# How do i set a value which is stored on db to a drop down as a default value.?

Tags: java

I stuck in retaining the dropdown value after  saving it to database.

Because in DB am storing a value by comma separated so am splitting it and getting two values .and am forcibly setting that values as default values to my dropdowns . But after saving the values are not retaining in the drop down. Please help me out. Thanks .

Please find the below code.

```
import pc.quote.Quote;
import cm.configurator.CustomHtmlComponent;
import cm.configurator.ExtFieldColumnXml;
import cm.gui.Cell;
import cm.gui.HtmlContainer;
import cm.gui.PullDown;
import cm.gui.Row;
import cm.gui.Style;
import cm.gui.Table;
import cm.html.HtmlSection;
import cm.persist.PersistUtil;
import cm.persist.PersistentObject;
import cm.util.TextOp;

public class TestComponentHc extends CustomHtmlComponent {
    private static String js_data_str = "";

    public TestComponentHc(HtmlSection sec) throws Exception {
        super(sec);
        pd_ = new PullDown(sec, null);
        //pulldown_ = new PullDown(sec, null);
        String prop = System.getProperty("FVCCatSubCat");
        js_data_str = " var Select_List_Data = { \n 'choices' : { \n ";
        if (!TextOp.isEmpty(prop)) {
            String[] vals = TextOp.split(prop, "|");
            pd_.addItem("", "");
            for (String val : vals) {
                if (TextOp.isEmpty(val))
                    continue;

                String[] keyToDepend = TextOp.split(val, ":");

                if (keyToDepend.length != 2)
                    continue;
                String text = keyToDepend[0];
                String key = text.replace(" ", "_");
                pd_.addItem(text, key);
                values = keyToDepend[1];
                System.out.println("Key>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + key);
                System.out.println("VALUES>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + values);
                String[] subcategories = TextOp.split(values, ",");
                js_data_str += " " + key + ": { \n value: ";
                js_data_str += "[";
                for (int i = 0; i < subcategories.length; i++) {
                    subcategory = subcategories[i];
                    // pulldown_.addItem(subcategory);
                    if (i > 0)
                        js_data_str += ",";
                    js_data_str += "'" + subcategory + "'";
                    System.out.print("   " + subcategory);
                }
                js_data_str += "]\n },";
            }
        }
        js_data_str += "}\n };";
    }

    /** added per sdr 183513 */
    public TestComponentHc() throws Exception {
        super(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void setExtFieldColumnXml(ExtFieldColumnXml efcx) {
    }

    public String key;
    public String values;
    public String subcategory;

    @Override
    protected void doAppendItem(StringBuffer b) throws Exception {
        pd_.setEditable(getIsEditable());
        pd_.setName(getName());
        pd_.setId("FvcCategories");
        pd_.addOnChange("getSubCategory(this);");
        pd_.setHeader("FVC Categories:");

        /*pulldown_.setName("FVCSUBCAT");
        pulldown_.setId("subcategory");
        pulldown_.setEditable(getIsEditable());
        pulldown_.setHeader("FVC Sub Categories:");*/



        //b.append("<select name=\"subcategory\" id=\"subcategory\">");

        //b.append("</select>");


        HtmlContainer cont = new HtmlContainer();
        Table table_ = createTable(cont, tableId);
        Row r = new Row();
        r.setStyle(new Style().setBold(false));
        table_.add(r);
        Cell c = new Cell();
        c.add("<label id=\"Label\"><font face=\"Verdana, Arial\" size=\"1\">FVC Categories</font></label></br>");
        r.add(c);
        Cell c1= new Cell();
        c1.add(pd_);
        r.add(c1);
        Cell c2= new Cell();
        c2.add("<select name=\"subcategory\" id=\"subcategory\">");
        r.add(c2);


    /*  
        Cell c2 = new Cell();
        c2.add(pulldown_);
        r.add(c2);
        c2.add("<label id='sublabel'><font face=\"Verdana, Arial\" size=\"1\">FVC Subcategories:</font></label></br>");
        r.add(c2);
        Cell c3 = new Cell();
        c3.add("<select name=\"subcategory\" id=\"subcategory\">");
        r.add(c3);
        Cell c4 = new Cell();
        c4.add(pulldown_);
        r.add(c4);
        */
        cont.appendHtml(b);



        getSection().needScript(
                "\n" + SCRIPT + "\n" + js_data_str + "\n" + SCRIPTING + "document.getElementById('subcategory').value='"+default_sub_value+"';\n" +"document.getElementById('FvcCategories').value='"+default_fvc_value+"';\n");

    }

    private static final String SCRIPT = "function SelectedItemCategory(obj) { \n"
            + "var itemSel = obj.value;"
            + "alert(itemSel);"
            + " if (itemSel == 'Fair Value' || itemSel == 'Both') { document.getElementsByName('quote_490')[0].style='display:block;';document.getElementById('subcategory').style='display:none;';} "
            + " else { document.getElementsByName('quote_490')[0].style='display:none;';document.getElementById('subcategory').style='display:none;'; document.getElementsByName('quote_490')[0].selectedIndex = 0; document.getElementId('subcategory').selectedIndex = 0;} \n"
            + "getSubCategory(document.getElementsByName('quote_490')[0]);\n"
            + "}\n"
            + "var element_FVC = document.getElementsByName('quote_117')[0]; "
            + "element_FVC.onchange = function() {\n"
            // onclick stuff
            + "alert(element_FVC.value);"
            + "SelectedItemCategory(document.getElementsByName('quote_117')[0]);{\n"
            + "};" + "}\n";

    private static final String SCRIPTING = "function removeAllOptions(sel, removeGrp) {\n"
            + "    var len, groups, par;\n"
            + "    if (removeGrp) {\n"
            + "        groups = sel.getElementsByTagName('optgroup');\n"
            + "        len = groups.length;\n"
            + "        for (var i=len; i; i--) {\n"
            + "            sel.removeChild( groups[i-1] );\n"
            + "        }\n"
            + "    }\n"
            + "    \n"
            + "    len = sel.options.length;\n"
            + "    for (var i=len; i; i--) {\n"
            + "        par = sel.options[i-1].parentNode;\n"
            + "        par.removeChild( sel.options[i-1] );\n"
            + "    }\n"
            + "}\n"
            + "\n"
            + "function appendDataToSelect(sel, obj) {\n"
            + "    var f = document.createDocumentFragment();\n"
            + "    var labels = [], group, opts;\n"
            + "    \n"
            + "    function addOptions(obj) {\n"
            + "        var f = document.createDocumentFragment();\n"
            + "        var o;\n"
            + "        \n"
            +

            "        for (var i=0, len=obj.value.length; i<len; i++) {\n"
            + "            o = document.createElement('option');\n"
            + "            o.appendChild( document.createTextNode( obj.value[i] ) );\n"
            + "            \n"
            + "            if ( obj.value ) {\n"
            + "                o.value = obj.value[i];\n"
            + "            }\n"
            + "            \n"
            + "            f.appendChild(o);\n"
            + "        }\n"
            + "        return f;\n"
            + "    }\n"
            + "    \n"
            + "    if ( obj.value ) {\n"
            + "        opts = addOptions(obj);\n"
            + "        f.appendChild(opts);\n"
            + "    } else {\n"
            + "        for ( var prop in obj ) {\n"
            + "            if ( obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) ) {\n"
            + "                labels.push(prop);\n"
            + "            }\n"
            + "        }\n"
            + "        \n"
            + "        for (var i=0, len=labels.length; i<len; i++) {\n"
            + "            group = document.createElement('optgroup');\n"
            + "            group.label = labels[i];\n"
            + "            f.appendChild(group);\n"
            + "            opts = addOptions(obj[ labels[i] ] );\n"
            + "            group.appendChild(opts);\n"
            + "        }\n"
            + "    }\n"
            + "    sel.appendChild(f);\n"
            + "}\n"
            + "function getSubCategory(currcatobj) {\n"
            + "var relName = 'choices';"
            + "var relList = document.getElementById('subcategory');"
            + "var obj = Select_List_Data[ relName ][ currcatobj.value ];"
            + "removeAllOptions(relList, true);"
            + "appendDataToSelect(relList, obj);" 
            + "if (currcatobj == '') \n"
            + "\t\tdocument.getElementById('subcategory').style='display:none';"
            + "else"
            + "\t\tdocument.getElementById('subcategory').style='display:block';"
            + "}\n";

    @Override
    public void setValue(Object o) throws Exception {
        quote_ = (Quote) o;
        po_ = (PersistentObject) o;
        System.out.println("SEQUENCE 2");

        String FvcCat = PersistUtil.getCustField(quote_, "TestComponent");
        if (FvcCat != null && !TextOp.isEmpty(FvcCat)) {
            System.out.println("FvcCat"+FvcCat);
            String[] Fvcvalues = TextOp.split(FvcCat, ",");
            if (Fvcvalues.length == 2) {
                 default_fvc_value= Fvcvalues[0];
                 default_sub_value = Fvcvalues[1];  
                System.out.println("default_fvc_value"+default_fvc_value+"default_sub_value"+default_sub_value);
            }           
        }


    }

    public String getSimpleText() throws Exception {
        return PersistUtil.getCustField(po_, field_);
    }

    private Table createTable(HtmlContainer cont, String id) {
        Table t = new Table();
        String color = "#FFFFFF";
        t.setWidthPercent(100);
        t.addAttribute("id", id);
        t.addAttribute("style", "border-collapse: collapse;");
        t.addAttribute("bgcolor", color);
        cont.add(t);
        return t;
    }


    private PullDown table_;
    private String tableId = "FVC_Table";
    private PullDown pd_;
    private PullDown pulldown_;
    private Quote quote_;
    private PersistentObject po_;
    private String field_;
    private String default_fvc_value;
    private String default_sub_value;
    @Override
    public boolean setChangesToObjectFromPage(PersistentObject po)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        quote_ = (Quote) po;

        String val = (String) pd_.getValueFromPage();
        /*String pulldownvalue = (String) pulldown_.getValueFromPage();
        System.out.println("PULL DOWN VALUE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+pulldownvalue);
        */
        String val2 =((getSection().getVal("subcategory")));
        PersistUtil.setCustField(quote_, "TestComponent", val + "," + val2 );


        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: why do you have javascript and jquery tags? I'm removing those...

Comment: I have two drop downs , based on the first drown keys,  i have to display respective values in second drop down .so am using that logic.

Comment: Am using JavaScript .

Comment: Where is it then? If you have Javascript post it. This is java, not javascript.